# cout does not name a type despite wrapped functions and namespace std

Tags: c++

I am getting the error 'cout does not name a type' (line 36 ie main function) along with a couple of other errors in main().

All code is wrapped well within the functions and I have used

```cpp
using namespace std;
```

but I am still getting this error along with other ~identifier~ was not declared in this scope errors in the main function.

Code:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

double discriminant (double a, double b, double c){
    return (pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c));
}

double* compute_roots(double a, double b, double c){
    double* x;
    double x1,x2;
    double d = discriminant(a,b,c);
    if (d>0){
        cout<<"Two real roots"<<endl;
    }
    else if (d=0){
        cout<<"One unique solution"<<endl;
    }
    else
        {
        cout<<"Does not support complex roots";
        //throw "Negative roots!";
        return x;
    }
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(d))/(2*a);
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(d))/(2*a);
    x[0] = x1;
    x[1] = x2;
    return x;
}

int main{
    double a=2.0,b=5,c=3.1;
    double* res=compute_roots(a,b,c);
    cout<<res[0];
    cout<<res[1];
    return 0;   
}
```

[image: sequence of errors]

Comment: What is the first error message?

Comment: Please always post the actual compiler error and warning messages *verbatim*.

Comment: Please post error messages as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: I'm sorry, next time for sure

Comment: @SG213 Why not [edit] this time to improve your question, instead of waiting for your next question when you probably would have forgotten the advise for this one?

Comment: Where is the 2 element array 'x' allocated (and later returned) in compute_roots?

Comment: `else if (d=0)` is suspicious.

Comment: So is `int main{`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> int main{
> ```

That should be

```
int main() {
```

Otherwise the compiler thinks you're trying to define an integer variable called `main`, not a function, and will get very confused by the code that follows.

Also, `compute_roots` never initializes its local variable `x` before using its value, so that can't work:

> ```
> double* x;
> // ...
> return x;
> ```

Another problem:

> ```
> else if (d=0){
> ```

should probably be `d == 0` (`=` is for assignment, not comparison).

Comment: @SG213 You also have a few other bugs in your code that a compiler can detect, see [compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/CVW2LA)

Answer (score 0):

the `main` function misses `()`. and you are using `d = 0` as the condition for `else if` not an error but it is not what you want. you also have memory leak.
this is probably what you need:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

double discriminant(double a, double b, double c) {
    return (pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c));
}
void deleter(double* x) {
    delete[] x;
}
shared_ptr<double> compute_roots(double a, double b, double c) {
    shared_ptr<double> x;
    x.reset(new double[2], deleter);
    double x1, x2;
    double d = discriminant(a, b, c);
    if (d > 0) {
        cout << "Two real roots" << endl;
    }
    else if (d == 0) {
        cout << "One unique solution" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Does not support complex roots";
        //throw "Negative roots!";
        return x;
    }
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a);
    x.get()[0] = x1;
    x.get()[1] = x2;
    return x;
}

int main() {
    double a = 2.0, b = 5, c = 3.1;
    shared_ptr<double> res = compute_roots(a, b, c);
    cout << res.get()[0];
    cout << res.get()[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why bother with `shared_ptr` and manual memory allocation? You could just return a `std::pair<double, double>`.

Comment: you are right, no need for a pointer here, I though he/she needs pointer for whatever reason.